# Convert string into three letter Abbreviation

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, logic

I've recently been given a new project by work to convert Any given string into 1-3 letter abbreviations.
An example of something similar to what I must produce is below however the strings given could be anything:

```
switch (string.Name)
        {
            case "Emotional, Social & Personal": return "ESP";
            case "Speech & Language": return "SL";
            case "Physical Development": return "PD";
            case "Understanding the World": return "UW";
            case "English": return "E";
            case "Expressive Art & Design": return "EAD";
            case "Science": return "S";
            case "Understanding The World And It's People"; return "UTW";

}
```

I figured that I could use string.Split & count the number of words in the array. Then add conditions for handling particular length strings as generally these sentences wont be longer than 4 words however problems I will encounter are.

1. If a string is longer than I expected it wouldn't be handled
2. Symbols must be excluded from the abbreviation

Any suggestions as to the logic I could apply would be very appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You seem to ignore "the" in "Understanding the World", but don't ignore "The" in "Understanding The World And It's People", is that because of capitalization?  Further are you expecting a given set of inputs to be abbreviated, as your `switch` seems to indicate, or do you expect the input to be dynamic?  If the former, you'd be better off using a `Dictionary`.

Comment: I would string.Split on a space. Iterate through each of the resulting strings, compare them to an exclusion list. If they are not in it, take the first letter of that word and capitalize it and move on. NOTE: replace any would be characters that might be used in the name '_' '-'.

Comment: @ChrisHandy That wouldn't work for either the 4th or last example because both have the work "the", but only one as a "T".

Comment: Yes the word "the" is ignored because of the capitalisation and the input will be dynamic. The switch is currently used as a temporary solution as I know of a few given string inputs. @juharr

Comment: Grammar nazi: it's *Its* in the last case, not It's.

Comment: @juharr 'The' doesn't have to be in the exclusion list like I said, where 'the' can be. If it isn't in the exclusion list then you take the first letter, thought that would be obvious. e.g "Cat and the Hat". 'and' and 'the' are in the exclusion list, leave them move to the next, so you end up with CH. "Cat and The Hat" would be CTH.

Comment: @ChrisHandy I agree with you partially because this is a similar solution that I had in mind however the exclusion list could work out to be pretty long. That's the only reason I was put off this solution. any idea on how to shorten this?

Comment: True, but you could use a Hashmap or similar for storing the exclusions. That way you check if string x exists in the hashmap ( don't need to iterate through everything ) and if not then you know it is a word that should be abbreviated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like the following should work with the examples you have given.

```
string abbreviation = new string(
    input.Split()
          .Where(s => s.Length > 0 && char.IsLetter(s[0]) && char.IsUpper(s[0]))
          .Take(3)
          .Select(s => s[0])
          .ToArray());
```

You may need to adjust the filter based on your expected input.  Possibly adding a list of words to ignore.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably do this

Comment: @juharr Very concise. +10

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if it doesn't matter, you could just go for the simplest thing. If the string is shorter than 4 words, take the first letter of each string.
If the string is longer than 4, eliminate all "ands", and "ors", then do the same.

To be better, you could have a lookup dictionary of words that you wouldn't care about - like "the" or "so".

You could also keep an 3D char array, in alphabetical order for quick lookup. That way, you wouldn't have any repeating abbreviations.

However, there are only a finite number of abbreviations. Therefore, it might be better to keep the 'useless' words stored in another string. That way, if the abbreviation your program does by default is already taken, you can use the useless words to make a new one.

If all of the above fail, you could start to linearly move through string to get a different 3 letter word abbreviation - sort of like codons on DNA.

Comment: presumably the returned values would be stored somewhere since I'm guessing you'd also need to ensure your not returning an abbreviation already used.

Comment: I can apply the majority of that logic except in a situation like the last case where the string is case "Understanding The World And It's People" the final word "People" maybe of more importance than "The"

Comment: @LeonWinston It does not look like the rules you are applying to create abbreviation are consistent

Comment: @LeonWinston Otherwise I got a solution

Comment: I believe so also,  I can't work out what consistent rules I could apply to abbreviation of an dynamic string, What would you suggest? @Alex

Comment: @LeonWinston Use of neural networks that would simulate human behaviour perhaps

Comment: @LeonWinston I think it would be a similar concept to a spell checker. You can create a statistical file of important words, and important words in context. 
http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html
I think the logic would be pretty similar to what the article explains

Answer (score 0):

Perfect place to use a dictionary

```
           Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                {"Emotional, Social & Personal", "ESP"},
                {"Speech & Language","SL"},
                {"Physical Development", "PD"}, 
                {"Understanding the World","UW"},
                {"English","E"},
                {"Expressive Art & Design","EAD"},
                {"Science","S"},
                {"Understanding The World And It's People","UTW"}
            };

            string results = dict["English"];​
```

Comment: Except that the OP has indicated that the inputs are dynamic.

Comment: Where does it say dynamic? And how to you determine which words to eliminate like 'the', 'and', 'it's', ...  Dictionaries can be dynamic if you have an algorithm that eliminates all the unwanted words.

Comment: Just going to paste this here: "work to convert **Any given string** into"

Comment: Also If you read the comments I specifically asked if the input could be dynamic and the OP answered.

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet may help you:

```
string input = "Emotional, Social & Personal"; // an example from the question 
string plainText = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Regex.Replace(input, @"[^0-9A-Za-z ,]", "").ToLower()); // will produce a text without special charactors
string abbreviation = String.Join("",plainText.Split(" ".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(y =>y[0]).ToArray());// get first character from each word
```